# Execute SQLITE query not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, forms, sqlite

I am trying to edit a row in my SQLite table with a button which will execute a SQLite query. But it doesn't change anything

Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FORM</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">
    <Link rel="stylesheet" href="ac.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ma.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
      date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

      $handle = new SQLite3("./d/idb.db"); 

      if(isset($_GET["index"])) {
        $sel = $_GET["index"]+1;
      } else {
         Header('Location: la.php');
         exit; 
      }

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $handle->query("UPDATE tri SET c = 'NM' WHERE mj = 4");
      }
    ?>
    <form>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="button">
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? There is not enough here for us to help you.

Comment: You need to show us _all_ the relevant code. But do what's suggested ^ first.

Comment: Also, you say it should "set cbn to NM" but your sql statement refers to column "c"

Comment: yeah typing error from my end. its edited.

Comment: Made some changes in my main poste.

Comment: So did that solve your issue? Or was it a typing error here on SO? If so, paste in _all the relevant_ code... the _actual_ code and not a rewrite. We can't help you find errors if you're not allowing us to see what's causing it.

Comment: I dont see what other relevant code i can add here. Its a simple button that will trigger my sqlite query. and it was only a typing error from my part here on SO.

Comment: Provide code like your html form and the complete php script

Comment: edited main poste with full code of the page.

Comment: your form should contains `method="post"` attribute